# why is token.pos_ not working while others token.lemma_ etc are working?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am trying to segreagte the sentences from a text file which has NOUN and VERB in it. But token.pos_ is not working whereas token.lemma_, token.shape_ etc are working. 
Hoping to get some help on this one. Below is the part of the code. Thank you in advance.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp = English()
sentencizer = nlp.create_pipe("sentencizer")
nlp.add_pipe(sentencizer)
doc = nlp(out_sent)

lis = []
new_lis = []
for d in doc.sents:
    lis.append(d)
print(lis)

for sent in lis:
    flag = 0
    for token in sent:
        # token.pos_ doesn't work. token.lemma_, token.shape_ etc works!
        #print(token.pos_)
        if(token.pos_ == 'NOUN' or token.pos_ == 'VERB'):
            flag = 1
    if(flag == 1):
        new_lis.append(sent)
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about "not working" - what happens exactly if you do `print(token.pos_)` ?

Comment: the print does not print anything, it should print NOUN or VERB, Does not even executes the if condition.

Comment: the print does not print anything, it should print NOUN or VERB, Does not even executes the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the following line from your code snippet:

`nlp = English()`

because it overwrites the line

`nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

The latter `en_core_web_sm` has a pretrained POS tagger, but `English()` is just a "blank" model that doesn't have such a POS tagger built-in. The model `en_core_web_sm` also can split sentences using the dependency parse, so there's no need to add the `sentencizer` to it.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for the solution and also for the explaination.